Specific Sub-plots for Each Clusters obtained from K-Means on a dataset
I have data set on which i applied k-means and corresponding data was classified into clusters now having identified the groups i want, side-by-side plot of some specific functions within the identified clusters i.e. if there are 5 clusters and each clusters contains 3 sub groups i should get a grid of 5 x 3 , where 5 is the no of clusters and 3 are the sub-groups within the cluster.
cluster_index = {}
for roll_stats in fund_rolling_stats:
 scheme_name = roll_stats['SCHEME_NAME'][0]
 if scheme_name in summary['SCHEME_NAME'].values:
     cindex = summary.loc[summary['SCHEME_NAME'] == scheme_name, 'Cluster'].values[0]        
     if cindex not in cluster_index:
         cluster_index[cindex] = []
     cluster_index[cindex].append(roll_stats)

summary dataframe contains the columns name, cluster_index and fund_rolling_stats is a list which contains data frame for each name.
Now i want to plot certain equation for each name in the list fund_rolling_stats such that name are grouped by there cluster index and side-by-side plot is created for each cluster_index i.e. comparision is to be made within the clusters only.

Please provide a short but complete example.
